# Trouble casting results of Select() to a List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What am I missing here?

I want to do a simple call to Select() like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();  
//fill the list
List<int> selections = (List<int>)list.Select(i => i*i); //for example
```

And I keep having trouble casting it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select() will return you an IEnumerable<int> type, you have to use the [ToList() operator](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ToListOperator.ashx):

```
List<int> selections = list.Select(i => i*i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Select() doesn't return a List so of course you can't cast it to a list.
You can use the ToList method instead:

```
list.Select(i => i*i).ToList();
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, I'm not sure the "of course" is valid... technically, the result of Select(...) **could** be a List<T> (masked as IEnumerable<T>). As it happens, it isn't, but that doesn't justify an "of course".

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which isn't actually a list - it's the result of a lazily-evaluated iterator block.

However, if you're dealing with lists and you want a list back out with nothing other than a projection, using [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) will be more efficient as it's able to create the new list with the right size immediately:

```
List<int> selections = list.ConvertAll(i => i*i);
```

Unless you particularly care about the efficiency, however, I'd probably stick to Select as it'll give you more consistency with other LINQ code.